# Windows 8 crashing unexpectedly

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, event-log, event-viewer

The computer I use at work sometimes crashes when I'm not near it. The first time it happened the OS crashed dead (even the mouse cursor wasn't moving). At that time I couldn't get much information from Event Viewer, but now it happened again (though it's also possible the second crash was unrelated to the first). This time the system became mostly unresponsive and I couldn't start the task manager to check what went wrong. After a moment of attempting to turn the machine off, all applications became unresponsive and I had to do a hardware reset (though the mouse was still responding).

This time the Even Viewer (Application section) was littered with errors related to SRUJet. Most of those errors said `Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.` and `attempt to load file failed` with error code 1011 (0xfffffc0d). The files in question appear to be `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SRU\SRU.chk` and `C:\WINDOWS\system32\SRU\SRU.log`. Incidentally the errors start at exactly 11:00:00.

In the system section of Event Viewer I noticed an unusual high number of `CFRMD (version 6.1, ‎2012‎-‎07‎-‎17T06:05:37.000000000Z) file system filter` errors. Stating something like `cannot attach to the volume` followed by either `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0` or `\Device\CdRom0` and `Filter returned non-standard end state 0xC01C0016`. At the time of the crash there are multiple `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0 device error detected during paging operation` errors.

At the time of the crash following applications were working (probably I forgot to mention a few):

- Visual Studio Express for Web 2012 (debugging an MVC app that was connected to local SQL Server database)
- SQL Server Express 2012 11.0.2100.60 (not sure about the version)
- IIS Express 8.0.8418.0 (not sure about the version)
- Firefox 33.0.2
- TortoiseHg 2.10.1
- Skype 6.20.0.104
- DropBox 2.10.30
- BTSync 1.4.93
- Notepad++ 6.6.9 (probably wasn't involved in the crash as I was able to close it)
- VisStart 8.1 build 5180 (not sure about the exact build)
- Comodo Antivirus 7.0.317799.4142 (at the time of the crash was reporting some malfunction and offering to fix it after system restart; during the first crash it was acting the same)
- MS Office Word 2007
- MS Excel Word 2007

**Now I'd like to figure why the crash occurred and prevent it from happening in the future.** The main suspect it FireFox which had a history of memory leaks on this very machine (eating up all available RAM), but I'm not sure how to verify that. I mean in the past FireFox was sometimes becoming sluggish and the system following suit. At those times Task Manager showed FireFox using insane amounts of memory. Closing FireFox (or killing it if closing was impossible) would make system regain the memory (though slowly after some time). I'm not sure what involvement SRUJet had in this crash.

The computer is a Toshiba laptop that has:

- i7-3630QM @ 2.40GHz
- 12 GB RAM
- Windows 8.1 64bit
- Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB

I preformed a disk check using HD Tune quick check after the second crash (the full check didn't work for some reason). This check did not report any errors. There were no worrying entries in the S.M.A.R.T. either.

Comment: What makes you think those application were not working?  Filesystem errors and systems being unresponsive point directly to a HDD failure because high I/O latency.  If you suspect Firefox.  Determine the reason its eating up all your memory, and update you question.

Comment: @Ramhound I think I wrote it worng. I meant that there might have been some other applications working (not that some of those might have not been working). As for FireFox, my guess is that after system run out of RAM it tried to switch the page repeatedly and fail at doing so (probably because the system needing stuff from RAM and page at the same time). I have no clue why FireFox has those memory leaks sometimes.

Comment: You need to track the cause of Firefox's memory problems.  I use Firefox and I never "run out of memory" and since you have 12GB of memory that should also be the case.  Be specific.  You say the "full check" provide specifics.

Comment: I'd suspect the antivirus.  Most are designed to run when the computer is "unused", so they wait until you walk away to do their nefarious deeds.  And most are poorly designed.

Comment: And the Firefox issue may indicate you've picked up a browser "adware" infection.  (Note that there should be only one small ad on the right side of this page.  If you see anything at the top you're infected.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I use AdBlock so I don't see any ads at all. Comodo sneakily installs some crapawere that is similar to AdBlock in some ways (except instead of hiding ads it replaces them with its own). I got rid of it though (at least that's what I believe). After turning AdBlock off I have a banner promoting Careers 2.0 at the top (aside from the ad on the right side).

Comment: Yep, sounds like adware.  What do you see on, eg, a Wikipedia page?  Should be nothing at all, other than the "sponsored links" that sometimes show up in the list or on the right side.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I had a look at the pages source and the banner (or rather the code that inits it) is already there. I think as a 4k+ user you have the privilege of not seeing the top banner on SE, while I with my measly 191 reputation have to see both the top banner and the one on the right side (at least when AdBlock is turned off). Edit: I don't have any ads on Wikipedia.